# Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (D:/RoR/projects/grp/public/uploads/

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to rename upload image

```
Permission denied @ sys_fail2 - (D:/RoR/projects/grp/public/uploads/gallery/test.jpg, D:/RoR/projects/grp/public/uploads/gallery/QINSNVZICC20160509132021.jpg)
```

My Code :

```
photo = params[:gallery][:gal_img]
name = photo.original_filename
directory = "#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/gallery/"
path = File.join(directory, name) 
uniq_name = (0...10).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
time_footprint = Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)
File.open(path, "wb") do |file|
  new_file_name = uniq_name + time_footprint + File.extname(file)
  file.write(photo.read)
  @uniq_path = File.join(directory, new_file_name)
  File.rename(file, @uniq_path)
end
```

I have checked and giving all the `privilege` in my ruby directory.

Please let me know why I am getting `Permission denied` error?

Comment: Double check that the user under which your Rails server is running has permissions to write to the gallery directory / the uploaded file.

Comment: did you figure this out? im running into the same issue

Comment: @JayLane no dear. Still not solved yet.